# Why do we not use $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon \text{ then } 0<|x-a|< \delta$ in the definition of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Why was the definition defines as
$$ \forall \epsilon >0 \exists  \delta \text{ such that   if } 0<|x-a|< \delta \text{ then } |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$$
Rather than
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists  \delta \text{ such that if } |f(x)-L|< \epsilon \text{ then } 0<|x-a|< \delta$$
The only reason I can think of is because $f(x)$ depends on $x$, but that isn't a satisfying answer since graphically it makes sense. That is as $f(x)$ gets closer to $L$, $x$ gets close to $a$. Secondly since it is for all $\epsilon$, it captures the idea of as "close as we want to $L$".

Side note
What's confusing me here is that these two statements seem to capture the same idea which isn't the case.I'm hoping someone points out what's wrong with the second statement.

Comment: In the second definition, the a constant function never has any limits. You seem to be equating two statements $P \implies Q$ and $Q \implies P$, which is not valid.

Comment: I know I'm equating to statements that are not logically equivalent. However they both seem to have the same idea about limits which is why in confused. Can you please explain further what you mean by "the constant function never has a limit"

Comment: But they don't have the same idea at all. One says that similar outputs have similar inputs, and the other says that similar inputs have similar outputs. The fact that constant functions have the same output regardless of input shows why your second definition *cannot* capture what we mean by limits.

Comment: The second one can tell you there's a limit when there isn't one: For any gap, the second one only checks values for which $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$ is true in the first place, which is meaningless. The first definition is exactly what you need to say that every arbitrarily small open neighborhood around L is the image of some open neighborhood, which is the idea...

Comment: Dear @dasaphro, It is not the case that "every small open neighborhood around $L$ is the image of some open neighborhood." What is true is that every ball around $L$ *contains* the image of some ball around $a$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell No, the epsilon-delta definition is equivalent to what I said. If $f:X \to Y$ then $f$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighborhood for every open neighborhood $V \subset Y$.

Comment: Plus, what you're trying to say is that "every ball around L *contains* the image of a point *contained* in some ball around $a$". The distinction is unnecessary.

Comment: Dear @dasaprho, I meant what I wrote. What you've written in your second post is true, but it's not the same as saying that every open neighborhood $V$ of $L$ in $Y$ is "the image of some open neighborhood." That would mean that there is an open set $U$ in $X$ such that $f(U)=V$. This is absolutely not the case for a general continuous function.

Comment: Oh, yeah I see the mistake now.

Comment: Please use titles that are more concise and to the point. My suggestion was: Why do we not use $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon \text{ then } 0<|x-a|< \delta$ in the definition of limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the  function $f$, defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1, &x>0 \\ 0, &x=0 \\ x-1, &x<0\end{cases}$$

Clearly, it is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Now apply your second definition of continuity.

$\forall \varepsilon >0, \ \ \exists \delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon \implies |x-a|< \delta$.

I claim that for every $\varepsilon$, we can choose $\delta= \varepsilon$.

If $\varepsilon<1$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ holds true only at $x=a$. So, $|x-a|<\delta$ is always true.

If $\varepsilon \geq 1$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ is true when $x\in (-\varepsilon+1, \varepsilon-1) \subseteq (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$. So, $|x-a|<\delta$ is also true for this case.

Thus, your definition is satisfied for a discontinuous function.